# Can't authenticate to dockerized mongodb instance with user created in script

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication

I have a mongo instance configured inside my docker-compose.yml as such (the variables come from my `.env` file, and I have no problem using the admin account so I don't think they are the cause of the issue):

```yaml
services:
    mongo:
        build: ./docker/mongo
        container_name: pname_mongo
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${MONGO_DATABASE}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./data/mongo:/data/db
```

Then inside `docker/mongo` is the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY graylog-user.js ./
```

The contents of `graylog-user.js` are thus:

```js
db.createUser({
    pwd: "redacted-password",
    roles: [{
        db: "graylog",
        role: "readWrite"
    }],
    user: "graylog"
});
```

After deleting the contents of `data/mongo` the database appears to be initialized correctly when I run `docker-compose up`:

```
mongo_1          | Successfully added user: {
mongo_1          |  "user" : "pname",
mongo_1          |  "roles" : [
mongo_1          |      {
mongo_1          |          "role" : "root",
mongo_1          |          "db" : "admin"
mongo_1          |      }
mongo_1          |  ]
mongo_1          | }
mongo_1          | Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory
mongo_1          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-02T21:43:01.568+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55612","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":0}}
mongo_1          | 
mongo_1          | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/graylog-user.js
mongo_1          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-02T21:43:01.627+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55616","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":1}}
mongo_1          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-02T21:43:01.628+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55616","client":"conn3","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.4.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"18.04"}}}}
mongo_1          | Successfully added user: {
mongo_1          |  "roles" : [
mongo_1          |      {
mongo_1          |          "db" : "graylog",
mongo_1          |          "role" : "readWrite"
mongo_1          |      }
mongo_1          |  ],
mongo_1          |  "user" : "graylog"
mongo_1          | }
mongo_1          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-02T21:43:01.679+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:55616","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":0}}
```

However, I haven't managed to be able to log on with this user no matter what I do. Here you can see me trying to log on using the cli inside the mongo container:

```
> use graylog
switched to db graylog
> db.auth({
...     user: "graylog",
...     pwd: "redacted-password",
...     digestPassword: false
... })
Error: Authentication failed.
0
> db.auth({
...     user: "graylog",
...     pwd: "redacted-password",
...     digestPassword: true
... })
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

When I log in, however, with the admin account I can see that the user is actually created (I've redacted all the hashes, salts, etc. I suppose they would change when deploying to production but better safe than sorry, right?):

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('pname', 'redacted-admin-password')
1
> show collections
system.users
system.version
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.pname", "userId" : UUID("a8f150a6-83f6-4fef-8457-a6afae5e6b72"), "user" : "pname", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "redacted", "storedKey" : "redacted", "serverKey" : "redacted" }, "SCRAM-SHA-256" : { "iterationCount" : 15000, "salt" : "redacted", "storedKey" : "redacted", "serverKey" : " to production" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "root", "db" : "admin" } ] }
{ "_id" : "pname.graylog", "userId" : UUID("4d13d6d6-1f19-4f7c-97ba-6aef11f88587"), "user" : "graylog", "db" : "pname", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "redacted", "storedKey" : "redacted", "serverKey" : "redacted" }, "SCRAM-SHA-256" : { "iterationCount" : 15000, "salt" : "redacted", "storedKey" : "redacted", "serverKey" : "redacted" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "graylog" } ] }
```

What am I missing? Have I skipped a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user `graylog` was created in database `pname`, and given readWrite permission to only db `graylog`.

That user will need to set authentication database to pname when connecting, but I don't think it is permitted to have a user created in a specific database to be granted permission to a different database.

You might try changing graylog-user.js to create the user in the graylog database:

```
db.getSiblingDB("graylog").createUser({
```

Comment: I was able to confirm that indeed the user was created for the main database. But when I first tried this solution it didn't work. It turns out I needed to rebuild the container (obvious when you think about it) and delete the contents of the data directory to force re-initialization. I might however go for a separate container for more granular scaling.